# Cx_Oracle DB connect issue from container running on EKS

Tags: python, oracle, amazon-eks, cx-oracle

I am having an issue connecting to on-prem Oracle databases from AWS EKS. The error I get is:

**"ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist".**

The the exact same script, from the exact same docker image, works fine when run from any other platform (not EKS).

Verified the firewall rules are in place by obtaining a shell on the pod and using telnet to the target. We do get a basic TCP connection, however any attempts to connect with the Cx oracle client fail with the above error.

Below is my cx oracle code, I don't feel there is a issue with how the connection string is passed, because the code works fine on different platform. Just that EKS container seems to have problems making a connection.

```
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host,port,service_name=service_name)
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user,password,dsn_tns,encoding = 'utf-8')
```

Comment: That's not an oracle problem, but hostname/dns resolution problem. Have you tried to use IP address instead of hostname?

Comment: Does it work from a lambda in your same network?

Comment: I have tried using IP address, get the same error. Haven't tried lambda, but it works on a ec2 hosted environment.  Telnet connects fine to the target host, but cx oracle fails, so not sure if it's a network issue.

Comment: I take my words back,  Sayan Malakshinov was right it was a hostname/DNS resolution issue. Earlier I was giving it SCAN IP's which still could not resolve to the oracle DB server. Giving the actual server host worked for me.